# Do we have any predefined job available in AX for Updating Inventory for multiple items? AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Do we have any job or class available ready to update onhand Inventory in AX?

I have an excel with values about inventory for items. I need to update them in AX. Can someone suggest ?

Comment: Not a good question for Stack Overflow, but I would suggest you try to use an inventory counting journal to do that. In AX 2012 you can use the predefined data import/export framework entity for inventory journals to import your excel data and create the journal. In AX 2009 probably the fastest way would be a custom job that imports data from a .csv created from the Excel data.

Comment: Check this blogs too. http://ax2012exceldataimport.blogspot.com/2012/01/dynamics-ax-2012-inventory.html  https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/timsaxblog/archive/2015/10/17/import-an-inventory-journal-in-ax-2012-r3

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to key-in into journal movement, or use DMF for import from excel.

Comment: Which DIXF entity I need to use for this?   What do you mean by Key-in into journal movement? Can you elaborate on how to do this key-in?